# Will implicit down-vote affect my reputation?

Tags: support, flagging, voting, down-votes

Sorry for misusing term *reputation*

I've observed that some flags (I don't remember which!)(If not all) Cast an implicit down-vote on post (again, I'm not sure about questions or answers). Will that down-vote which I didn't cast show up in my *down-vote* count? (And this was the *reputation* I was talking about)

Comment: Does [this Help Center page](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) answer part of your question?

Comment: @robjohn No it's not about *rep* (points)

Comment: The flags that cause $-100$ reputation are not downvotes (though the system may impose a downvote). Besides, since you didn't cast a downvote, no downvote will show up on your profile for flagging a post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only flags that work this way are Spam and Offensive/Abusive. When a user casts one of these flags, a downvote is automatically given by the [Community bot](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community). It is not *your* vote: it does not show up on the /votes tab of your profile, and you cannot undo it.

---

Usual reminder to be *extra* careful with these flags: they are meant exactly for what they are named for. Commercial advertisement (e.g., selling skin care products), offensive tirades, cat-on-keyboard  posts.

Comment: What do you mean by "cat-on-keyboard posts" and how should they be flagged?

Comment: @quid Example: `dfojaifojadiofjadhigaowkokaomdiovnuiyhiio`. [If someone is abusing the site by posting gibberish, flag it as such.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234035/)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. The question this raises is if each post of this form is somebody abusing the site. (Shog9 is not quite clear here.) Personally I would hesitate to flag this as offensive if it came once from an account that seems legitimate.

Comment: I would look into it deeper if such a post came from an account with >1 reputation. So far, this hasn't been observed by me.

Comment: Ah, I usually flag the cat-on-keyboard kind of answers as low quality. I think this flag description fits better than that for the abusive, but I can change...

Comment: Also, I love the fact that you copied the example verbatim from the linked meta question, @Rafflesiaarnoldii

Comment: @DanielR It's not copied verbatim; there are a few subtle differences. Yes, flagging is subjective (as Shog9 acknowledges in comments there), and VLQ is definitely a valid flag.